# Using Python Pillow lib to set Color depth

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am using the Python Pillow lib to change an image before sending it to device.
I need to change the image to make sure it meets the following requirements

- Resolution (width x height) = 298 x 144
- Grayscale
- Color Depth (bits) = 4
- Format = .png

I can do all of them with the exception of Color Depth to 4 bits.
Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Comment: You want to change it to 4-bit gray-scale level image, or 4-bit for each channel in RGB?

Comment: @Marcin The spec doesn't say which but i would think it means "4-bit gray-scale level image"

Answer (score 6):

So far, I haven't been able to save 4-bit images with Pillow. You can use Pillow to reduce the number of gray levels in an image with:

```
import PIL.Image as Image
im = Image.open('test.png')
im1 = im.point(lambda x: int(x/17)*17)
```

Assuming test.png is a 8-bit graylevel image, i.e. it contains values in the range 0-255 (im.mode == 'L'), im1 now only contains 16 different values (0, 17, 34, ..., 255). This is what ufp.image.changeColorDepth does, too. However, you still have a 8-bit image. So instead of the above, you can do

```
im2 = im.point(lambda x: int(x/17))
```

and you end up with an image that only contains 16 different values (0, 1, 2, ..., 15). So these values would all fit in an uint4-type. However, if you save such an image with Pillow

```
im2.save('test.png')
```

the png will still have a color-depth of 8bit (and if you open the image, you see only really dark gray pixels). You can use PyPng to save a real 4-bit png:

```
import png
import numpy as np
png.fromarray(np.asarray(im2, np.uint8),'L;4').save('test4bit_pypng.png')
```

Unfortunately, PyPng seems to take much longer to save the images.

Answer (score 0):

using changeColorDepth function in ufp.image module.

```
import ufp.image
import PIL
im = PIL.Image.open('test.png')
im = im.convert('L') # change to grayscale image
im.thumbnail((298, 144)) # resize to 294x144
ufp.image.changeColorDepth(im, 16) # change 4bits depth(this function change original PIL.Image object)
#if you will need better convert. using ufp.image.quantizeByImprovedGrayScale function. this function quantized image.
im.save('changed.png')
```

see example : [image quantize by Improved Gray Scale. [Python]](http://runnable.com/VQ5o_OpMIyQdA6zE/image-quantize-by-improved-gray-scale-for-python)

Comment: ImportError: No module named ufp.image getting this error please help

Comment: the ufp.image code is here : https://github.com/Thestars3/pyufp/blob/master/ufp/image.py . Function changeColorDepth uses PIL only in a similar way than @Thomas code below

Comment: -1 just because this is an unmaintained package whose docs are *in part* only available in Korean and *in part* no longer easily available at all because they've been replaced with a redirect to Rick Astley's *Never Gonna Give You Up* on YouTube. Maybe the underlying code is nonetheless good but IMO it'd be preferable to quote the implementation of the relevant functions rather than suggest depending on an unmaintained package whose docs most readers can't understand without Google Translate.